# How do you get a WPF TextBox to overflow to the left and stay that way without messing up your arrow key behavior?

Tags: wpf, layout, textbox, alignment

I have a text box that is only 10 characters wide.  I need to put 20 characters in it, but only need to show the last 10 characters.  I need to force the TextBox to always overflow the text to the left, thus allowing the 10 characters on the right to be visible.

I have looked at several postings and tried all the recommendations I could find, but they don't seem to work properly.

Here are the things I have tried so far (by themselves and in combinations):

```
<TextBox 
    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
    TextAlignment="Right"
    FlowDirection="RightToLeft"/>
```

Seems like FlowDirection is the closest thing to get it to work, but it makes the left and right arrow keys operate backwords..  (you press the left key, the cursor inside the TextBox moves to the right)  Also, when you tab off the control after editing the left most text, the text doesn't pop back and show the rightmost characters again.

TextAlignment will just push the text to the right if there isn't enough text to fill the box.

HorizontalContentAlignment doesn't appear to be helping at all...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this small example:

First, the XAML of the window:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="1234567890" Width="40" Name="MyTextBox" LostFocus="MyTextBox_LostFocus" />
        <TextBox Text="" Width="40" Name="MyTextBox2" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

And some code behind:

```
    private void MyTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
        MyTextBox.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(999999);
    }
```

This will only accomplish what you're looking for when the focus is lost. You may have to call `ScrollToHorizontalOffset()` after your view is loaded to have the TextBox start off that way. And there might be a better way to determine the parameter. `double.MaxValue` might be a better choice.

Comment: No problem. If you ever need to scroll a text box to the bottom you can use the same technique for the vertical scrolling. I found this out when I had a text box I used like a console window.